# Using LaTeX-length in the options interface of \documentclass and \usepackage

Tags: koma-script

The [Koma-Script manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) states (English translation, 2017-04-13, p. 30):

> the options interface of `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` is not robust. [...] So, if you want to use a `LaTeX` length [...] a part of the value of an option, you **have** to use `\KOMAoptions` or `\KOMAoption`.

(the emphasis is mine).

Two pages later (p. 32), the following example is given:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[BCOR=8.25mm]{typearea}
```

The example uses a length (namely 8.25mm) in the options interface of a `\usepackage` command rather than in a `\KOMAoptions` or a `\KOMAoption` command. On the face of it, this is in contradiction to the quote cited above. What's the catch?

Comment: I think `LaTeX` length means something like `\baselineskip` and not a fixed value like `8.25mm`.

Comment: @esdd: Indeed, changing the `8.25mm` value to `\baselineskip` results in an error. Is there a list of all LaTeX lengths such as `\baselineskip`?

Comment: Is there any news here? Basically, you misread the documentation. Or should @esdd add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: No news. I don't know that I misread the documentation. I'd say the documentation is not clear enough. If esdd wants to add an answer, they are welcome to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"LaTeX length" are all dimensions and skips defined by `\newlength`, `\newdimen` or `\newskip`, eg. `\baselineskip`.  Floating point numbers with a unit like `8.25mm` are not LaTeX length.